# pandas turning all strings into numbers ( one hot encoding) for regression

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, regression, preprocessor

I am trying to preprocess data that looks like this :

```
train.head(4)

    Id  MSSubClass  MSZoning    LotFrontage LotArea Street  Alley   LotShape    LandContour Utilities   ... PoolArea    PoolQC  Fence   MiscFeature MiscVal MoSold  YrSold  SaleType    SaleCondition   SalePrice
0   1.0 60.0    RL  65.0    8450    Pave    NaN Reg Lvl AllPub  ... 0   NaN NaN NaN 0   2   2008    WD  Normal  208500
1   2.0 20.0    RL  80.0    9600    Pave    NaN Reg Lvl AllPub  ... 0   NaN NaN NaN 0   5   2007    WD  Normal  181500
2   3.0 60.0    RL  68.0    11250   Pave    NaN IR1 Lvl AllPub  ... 0   NaN NaN NaN 0   9   2008    WD  Normal  223500
3   4.0 70.0    RL  60.0    9550    Pave    NaN IR1 Lvl AllPub  ... 0   NaN NaN NaN 0   2   2006    WD  Abnorml 140000
4 rows × 81 columns
```

I have to find a way to turn these strings into numbers, so that I can use them for regression. I also aware that if I simply number them, I might get introduce a wrong distance logic to it ( not one hot encoded). Does someone know a a smart way to do this?

N

Comment: label encode ? sklearn

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(train)`

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much! Can I assume that this command automatically recognize when it is "needed" so not converting perfectly fine integers?

Comment: It will convert integers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pandas.get_dummies()` to encode categorical data. You can see the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). It won't convert your integer values (i.e. it will leave them intact. See this example from official documentation).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                    'C': [1, 2, 3]})

pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['col1', 'col2'])
   C  col1_a  col1_b  col2_a  col2_b  col2_c
0  1       1       0       0       1       0
1  2       0       1       1       0       0
2  3       1       0       0       0       1
```

If the number of categorical features are large and the number of unique values per categorical is large as well, you can try Scikit-learn's DictVectorizer. See the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) .

You can check [this link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10839/what-is-difference-between-one-hot-encoding-and-leave-one-out-encoding/10843) to see which encoding to use based on your algorithm.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is there an internal logic that leads to two dataframes being converted in the same way if they have the same values. Meaning, if I convert a test and a train set like that, will they have the same values afterwards as well.

Comment: It's not a stupid question :-) . Your assumption is correct. If the values are same in two dataframes, they will be converted in the same way. But just be sure that the train and test have the same unique categorical values. A better idea would be to split into train and test after performing get_dummies operation.